# Does Symfony2 / FOSUserBundle do any of these?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have been learning Symfony2 / Security / Authentication / FOSUserBundle and I can't seem to find this functionality. If it doesn't exist and if anyone can point me in the right direction to ready-made bundles or advice I would appreciate it. Of course I may have to write everything myself from scratch, but a bundle would be nice!

Any advice or pointers will help me to put all this together. There is of course many hours of work here, so I'm just looking for a starting point. Thanks for any help.

(1) last active time. Not just 'last logged in' time, but something that updates every time the user makes a page request.

(2) Suspend after failed login attempts. So if a user fails 3 login attempts then lock them out for 10 minutes or so (and they can't login even if they get the correct username/password).

(3) Remember-me but still requires a 4 digit pin. So a user can click the remember me option and on returning it remembers them, but instead of requiring a full login it asks for a 4 digit pin code - makes it a lot easier than entering a full username and password every time but also more secure than just using the remember-me option.

(4) 'Must Action' area. When they log-in sometimes notes have been attached to their account for things they 'must action'. This could be a new user needing to confirm something, or maybe an important message someone must see. When they go to login it diverts them to a certain URL and they must click to confirm before they can do anything else.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK :

1. : No.
2. : No.
3. : No.
4. : No.